# Accuracy Matlab's slash matrix operators

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose we have these 3 matrices:

```
A=[1 3; 2 2];    B=[4 5; 1 3];     C=[0 2; 2 1]
```

Usually, I try to avoid using inv() or A^(-1) and try to use forward- and backslash operators instead. But if I want to calculate the following:

```
A*B^(-1)*C
```

which way is the best:

```
A/B*C
```

or

```
A*(B\C)
```

Although both use the slash operators and no "explicit inverse" is being calculated, the result is a different and interestingly, A*(B\C) calculates the same as the one I'm trying to avoid, which is

```
A*inv(B)*C
```

as

```
isequal(A*(B\C),A*inv(B)*C)
```

shows. Can anyone explain what is happening here and which way I should go? Thanks!

Comment: While `isequal(A*inv(B)*C, A/B*C)` returns 0, the difference is on the order of machine epsilon and for all intents and purposes may as well be 0. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, all three statements are essentially equivalent. That said, `tic/toc` for me yields `A/B*C` takes 59us and `A*(B\C)` takes 76us. The difference in time may be because the order of operations is not left-to-right for `A*(B\C)`.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB has some serious strategy behind `mldivide`: see the Algorithm section of the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html). I can image that it decides that inversing matrices of size 2×2 is the quickest way for solving and hence it calls `inv` and hence explicitely computes the inverse of `B`. For larger matrices, this is not the case and if I pick random matrices of size 4×4, executing the `isequal`-sentence returns false.

Anyway, the 'best' approach highly depends on your matrices `A`, `B` and `C`.

---

After some testing, I found that `A*inv(B)*C` always takes more time than `A*(B\C)`, which means that it can also just be a machine-precision thing (see Dang Khoa's useful comment). Still, there is no single 'best' approach for `mldivide` versus `mrdivide`.